is minimal edge of a certain vertix in MST
Assume $G = (V,E)$ is undirected graph with weight function: $w: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $T = (V,\tilde{E})$ MST of $G$.
Is it true that for all  $v \in V$ is it necessary that the minimal edge connected for v is in T?
Formally : $$ \forall v \in V: e_{\text{min}} = \arg\min_{e \in E(v)} w(e) \in \tilde{E} $$
I know it is true for the "global" minimal edge, but i couldn't prove this or find a counterexample.

Yes, it's true. You should be able to prove it by showing that Kruskal's algorithm will always select that edge.
